# Symmetrize and Mirror

Tags: mesh, modifiers, sculpting, mirror, multiresolution

I’ve been following a tutorial on YT, I've completed the base mesh for a character from a cube privative.
The next tutorial is setting up for sculpting. I'm in *Sculpting* > *Sculpt Mode*, I have *Multi-Resolution Modifier* and the *Mirror Modifier*, I'm ready to sculpt. Tutorials say click Subdivide, how do I know it has?
I read about Symmetrize and Mirror, what's the difference?

Comment: Hello, just to be clear, you want to know the difference between symmetrize and mirror features ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, and how they work together. If I click the subdivide half my character disappears along the Z axis, this also happens if I delete my mirror mod? which is under the Multires in the stack, I've seen this problem appear in the FAQ's.

Answer (score 0):

To know you've subdivided, you can look at your multiresolution modifier and it will say how many subdivisions you have done and will give you options for what to show for Level Viewport, Sculpt, and Render. It should also look smoother now that you've subdivided and have twice the amount of geometry.

Symmetrize does the same operation as mirror modifier, but you can turn mirror modifier off while with symmetrize you can only go back with Undo.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Looking back at the first part of the question, If I click the subdivide half my character disappears along the Z axis, this also happens if I delete my mirror mod? which is under the Multires in the stack, I've seen this problem appear in the FAQ's. I can't seem to add a photo/screenshot.

Comment: Half of the object should only disappear if you deactivate your mirror modifier. When you are in edit mode, it will also only shows your model without the mirror modifier. This is because in edit mode you are only editing the basemesh. The only exception is the multiresolution modifier where you can move, but not add or delete geometry unless you subdivide.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think I'm putting over my problem/question that well. I'm ready to sculpt in Sculpting > Sculpt Mode. I click subdivide (Multires) and half disappears! It's the tutorial I'm following saying that says this to add more detail.

Comment: If your object doesn't have a mirror modifier and still half of disappears when you subdivide it, I don't have a solution. If you share the Blender file, I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks for that. How and where do I share the file?

Comment: I searched online and found the website "pastebin" has a file sharing of 5 gb max.